# TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined react

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am new to react js and following react code giving me this error
 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined at Button (D:\my-app.next\server\static\PqudrDXAzXfiQCJ2zK-7F\pages\index.js:408:59)."

please assist me to solve this, thank you.

here is my index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from '../components/head';
import Nav from '../components/nav';
import Button from '../components/Button';
export default () => (
<div>
<Head title="Home" />
<Nav />
<Button text="Demo Button" />
</div>
);
```

and here is my Button.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './button.css';
import { string } from 'prop-types';

const Button = (props) => (
<button>{ props.text } </button>
);
Button.propTypes = {
text: string
 };

export default Button;
```

Comment: you should return you JSX. i.e. `return ( <button>.... ),` and `return (<div><Head...`

Comment: hi @tikkes, thanks for replying. can you please tell me how should return statement be use in this case.

Comment: It is not necessary as in arrow functions if you omit curly brackets you return the following statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this working example:

[image: Edit sleepy-hamilton-khhmp]

```
import React from "react";
import { string } from "prop-types";
const Button = props => <button> {props.text} </button>;
Button.propTypes = {
  text: string
};
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Button text="Demo Button" />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: thanks @radulle its working for me, that was so easy.